# Is my gulpfile.js with errors? I face different issues and can't get it to work

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, gulp, src

So I have mainly these 2 problems which happen rather randomly:

- html file from SRC folder is not copied to DIST.
- js files are not concateneted and nor copied to DIST.

Am I'm doing something wrong?
Recent problem I had:
- spent hours trying to get Owl carousel work, just to realise the js files were not loaded and compiled. I'm calling main.min.js at the end of my html file, but still, in the html file it only gets changed in SRC folder and not copied to DIST.

I do not get errors in terminal, nor in console. The only error I get is that I need to load popper.js for bootstrap to work, so something works... I'm not sure.

Here's my gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp'),
    plumber = require('gulp-plumber'),
    rename = require('gulp-rename');
var autoprefixer = require('gulp-autoprefixer');
var babel = require('gulp-babel');
var concat = require('gulp-concat');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var imagemin = require('gulp-imagemin'),
    cache = require('gulp-cache');
var minifycss = require('gulp-minify-css');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var browserSync = require('browser-sync');

gulp.task('browser-sync', function() {
  browserSync({
    server: {
       baseDir: "dist/"
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('bs-reload', function () {
  browserSync.reload();
});

gulp.task('images', function(){
  gulp.src('src/img/**/*')
    .pipe(cache(imagemin({ optimizationLevel: 3, progressive: true, interlaced: true })))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/img/'));
});

gulp.task('styles', function(){
  gulp.src(['src/scss/**/*.scss'])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(sass())
    .pipe(autoprefixer('last 2 versions'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(minifycss())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/css/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('scripts', function(){
  return gulp.src([
  'src/js/jquery.js',
  'src/js/bootstrap.min.js',
  'src/js/tether.js',
  'src/js/owl.carousel.js',
  'src/js/custom.js'
    ])
    .pipe(plumber({
      errorHandler: function (error) {
        console.log(error.message);
        this.emit('end');
    }}))
    .pipe(concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(babel())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'))
    .pipe(rename({suffix: '.min'}))
    .pipe(uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest('dist/js/'))
    .pipe(browserSync.reload({stream:true}))
});

gulp.task('copy', function() {
  gulp.src('src/**/*.html')
  .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'))
});

gulp.task('default', ['browser-sync'], function(){
  gulp.watch("src/scss/**/*.scss", ['styles']);
  gulp.watch("src/js/**/*.js", ['scripts']);
  gulp.watch("src/**/*.html", ['copy', 'bs-reload']);
});
```

Comment: Fixed the first problem of gulp not copying the html from SRC to DIST.
It seems that you need to put 'DIST/' not 'DIST'. That slash is important for specifying destination.
Still.. my js files are not loaded, they only work if I request them separately from my html file with <script> tags. Anyone have any idea?

Comment: So the main.min.js file is loaded, however it seems there might be some conflicting issues with jQuery. When I concat jquery, bootstrap.js, tether.js and owl-carousel.js it doesn't work. When I load them separately it does. Any idea how to avoid conflict issues? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution.
It seems that bootstrap.js goes in conflict with owl-carousel.js if you use it the way I did. The correct order for this to work is:

```
'src/js/jquery.js',
'src/js/owl.carousel.js',
'src/js/custom.js',
'src/js/tether.js',
'src/js/bootstrap.js'
```

So although it seems intuitive to declare jquery first, then bootstrap, you actually need to leave bootstrap at the end.